# Does saving to context in MVC update object attributes?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I was wondering If it was always the case that saving an object to the db in ASP MVC updates the fields of the object?

Just for illustration say I have a Student class with fields ID (int) and Name where.

The key for the records is clearly ID

If I have a student: `Student student = new Student("studentName");`

and do

```
Context.Insert(student); ID will be assigned a number
Context.Save();
```

Is it always safe after such operation to assume that "student" ID has been updated? Or do I have to query it from the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... It depends! :)
You are describing a case where EF conventions are doing some of the work for you.
Code First convention looks for fields that are named Id or [class name]Id and determines that these are meant to be keys for the classes. You class design simply match this convention.Because you Id property is integer type, EF has also configured it to be identity column in the database. So, when you save your object, your database generates the Id and you context is updated acordingly.

About documentation, Julia Lerman three books about EF are a must.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So If the ID is declared as **int? ID** and therefore null when the object is created. after adding and saving is the object ID ALWAYS automagically updated? Specific documentation preferred. I don't really feel like reading three books to find the answer :D

Comment: Yes.
Even if you declare Id as nullable, the convention will work the same: Id column in the DB will be: (1) not null, (2) Identity.
after adding your object to the context and calling savechanges your context will update your entity with the Id generated from db.
Check [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx) for Primary Key Convention and  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) for Entity states and SaveChanges. Just

Comment: Just to clarify: because the id is database generated (unless you overide the convention) the object gets the Id AFTER calling context.SaveChanges() not before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only saving, yes, ID will be automatically incremented.

But if you are going to edit/delete a certain record, you need to query the id first before firing

```
Context.Save()
```

Comment: Thanks Louis. Any documentation you can point me to? Or maybe this is just common sense?

Comment: Why don't you check this out : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2013/09/20/managing-entity-relationships-with-mvc-scaffolding.aspx